# Can I convert comma-separated string back to AD value objects?

Tags: arrays, powershell, active-directory, export-to-csv

So I'm trying to write a script that will generate an AD report based on parameters chosen by the user, and it's caused me a lot more headache than I expected.  Here's an excerpt of what I'm trying to do:

```
#import the ActiveDirectory Module 
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 

#report parameter variables
$firstname = {givenname}
$lastname = {surname}
$displayname = {DisplayName}
$logonname = {sAMAccountName}

#set array initially to number of possible parameters
$inputarray = (0..3)


#display menu
cls
Write-Host "Please select the parameters you would like in your report:"
Write-Host "Enter q when finished"
Write-Host `n
Write-Host " 1) First Name"
Write-Host " 2) Last Name"
Write-Host " 3) Display Name"
Write-Host " 4) Logon Name"
Write-Host `n

#read in selections from user while input isn't Q, and not bigger than array 
#bounds   
for ($i=0; (($i -le 3) -and ($inputarray[$i] -ne 'q')); $i++){

$selection = ($i + 1)       
    $inputarray[$i] = Read-host "Enter report parameter $selection"

    #exit loop for quit selection    
    if ($inputarray[$i] -eq 'q'){
        break
    }

    switch ($inputarray[$i])
    {
        "1" { $result = $firstname }
        "2" { $result = $lastname }
        "3" { $result = $displayname }
        "4" { $result = $logonname }
    }

    $inputarray[$i] = $result
}

$arraylen = $i
$test = ''

for ($x=0; $x -lt $arraylen; $x++){
    if($x -lt ($arraylen -1)){
        $test = ($test + $inputarray[$x] + ',')
    }
    else{
        $test = ($test + $inputarray[$x])
    }
}

Get-ADUser -searchbase "my targeted OU" -Properties * -Filter * |
Select-Object $test |
Export-Csv -Path "export path here.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

I thought creating a string from the array with comma separated values would work the same as typing them in (like Select-Object givenname,surname,lastlogin) but that clearly isn't working.  Any ideas how to change it back from a string value to individual objects, so maybe it will accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st problem: Statements such as `$firstname = {givenname}` assign a [*script block* (`{...}`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks) to the variable, which is not your intent; instead, you're looking to assign property names as *strings*, e.g., `$firstname = 'givenname'`.

2nd problem: You're building variable `$test` as a *string*, whereas what you need to pass to `Select-Object` is an *array* of strings (property names), so you can just use `$inputArray` directly.

Comment: @lazyindfw: Glad to hear it; my pleasure.